# Mysql server shutdowns when Explain extended is executed for certain queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a really weird problem with MySQL server

When I execute for example:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT PRODNO,
          DT,
          FLAG1,
          FLAG2,
          `ORDER`,
          `QUANTITY`,
          `CARRYOVER`,
          `RETURNS`,
          `QUANTITY` + `CARRYOVER` - `RETURNS` AS `TOTALMARKET`
   FROM   (SELECT  NAME_CONST('_DATE',_binary'2011-02-20' COLLATE 'binary') AS wdt
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NAME_CONST('_DATE',_binary'2011-02-20' COLLATE 'binary'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK )) AS wdt
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NAME_CONST('_DATE',_binary'2011-02-20' COLLATE 'binary'), INTERVAL 2 WEEK )) AS wdt
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NAME_CONST('_DATE',_binary'2011-02-20' COLLATE 'binary'), INTERVAL 3 WEEK )) AS wdt
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NAME_CONST('_DATE',_binary'2011-02-20' COLLATE 'binary'), INTERVAL 4 WEEK )) AS wdt
             ) days
          JOIN bbproduct b
            ON b.dt = days.wdt
   WHERE  ROUTENO =  NAME_CONST('_ROUTENO',3)
   ORDER  BY DT DESC,
             PRODNO ASC
```

Server version: 5.1.31-community

This simply shutdowns the MySQL server. What could be wrong?

Comment: Please check your errorlog and print the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `COLLATE 'binary'` stuff.